# string concatenation runtime performance

Tags: javascript, php, big-o

In JavaScript, string concatenation is known to be O(n^2) so it is recommended to use

```
['string one', 'string two', 'string three'].join()
```

to concatenate strings.

Is this also true in PHP?

Is there a performance difference between

```
<?php $string .= $string1 . $string2; ?>
```

and

```
<?php $string = implode(array('string1', 'string2', 'string3')); ?>
```

Comment: that's actually a slower way to build strings in V8...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to use arrays to concatenate string in PHP - except you have an array as input or want to create an csv lists, etc.

Strings in PHP are `mutable`, means: they "Can change". Other languages like Java, C#, etc. have `immutable` string, which require a lot more logic to concatenate. When you change an immutable string, you have to create a new one.